# MySQL Delete rows from table dependent on over

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I am trying to delete rows from map_points table where I supply a place_id, but only delete if the place_id is not an ancestor of another place_id entered for the same map_id

```
CREATE TABLE map_points {
    map_id int,
    place_id int
}

CREATE TABLE place_relation {
    ancestor int,
    child int
}


| map_id | place_id |
+--------+----------+
|   10   |    20    |
|   10   |    22    |
|   12   |    20    |
|   12   |    31    |
|   12   |    21    |
|   13   |    20    |
|   13   |    44    |
|   14   |    33    |
|   14   |    31    |
|   14   |    20    |
|   14   |    44    |
+--------+----------+


| ancestor | child |
+----------+-------+
|   20     |   22  |
|   20     |   21  |
|   31     |   33  |
+----------+-------+
```

I want to delete the map_points that have a place_id = 20, but not if the place has a child in the place_relation table. After executing the delete the result set should look as follows.

```
| map_id | place_id |
+--------+----------+
|   10   |    20    |
|   10   |    22    |
|   12   |    20    |
|   12   |    31    |<- deleted
|   12   |    21    |
|   13   |    20    |<- deleted
|   13   |    44    |
|   14   |    33    |
|   14   |    31    |
|   14   |    20    |<- deleted
|   14   |    44    |
+--------+----------+
```

Here is where I'm at, but it is deleting too many records

```
DELETE p
FROM map_points p
    JOIN place_relation r ON r.ancestor = p.place_id
    LEFT JOIN map_points p2 ON p2.map_id = p.map_id AND p2.place_id = r.child
WHERE p.place_id IN ( 20, 31 )
AND p2.place_id IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

I have removed one of the criteria from the LEFT JOIN, but now nothing is deleted

```
DELETE p
FROM map_points p
    JOIN place_relation r ON r.ancestor = p.place_id
    LEFT JOIN map_points p2 ON p2.place_id = r.child
WHERE p.place_id IN ( 20, 31 )
AND p2.place_id IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

Based on the original criteria the following query gives the correct results

```
DELETE p
FROM map_points p
    JOIN place_relation r ON r.ancestor = p.place_id
    LEFT JOIN map_points p2 ON p2.map_id = p.map_id AND p2.place_id IN (
        SELECT child
        FROM place_relation 
        WHERE r.ancestor = ancestor 
    )
WHERE p.place_id IN ( 20, 31 )
AND p2.place_id IS NULL
```

**UPDATED**

While working with the query I updated place_relation table by adding a row that more accurately reflects the data in our active database.

```
| ancestor | child |
+----------+-------+
|    20    |   22  |
|    20    |   21  |
|    21    |   22  |*
|    31    |   33  |
+----------+-------+
```

Desired end result

```
| map_id | place_id |
+--------+----------+
|   10   |    20    |
|   10   |    21    |* // all ancestors are added to map_points table
|   10   |    22    |
|   12   |    20    |<- deleted
|   12   |    31    |<- deleted
|   12   |    21    |<- deleted
|   13   |    20    |<- deleted
|   13   |    44    |
|   14   |    33    |
|   14   |    31    |
|   14   |    20    |<- deleted
|   14   |    44    |
+--------+----------+
```

Then added 21 to the WHERE criteria 
    ...
    WHERE p.place_id IN (20,21,31)

The resulting DELETE did not remove row (12,20) from the map_points table.

So, it looks like this query can only take one value in the WHERE criteria.  Thus, the data will need to be sorted before the delete statement is executed one value at a time.

Is there a way to write the query so multiple values can be entered in the WHERE criteria?

**UPDATED**

To get the desired result with multiple values it seems that I have to enter the multiple values in the subselect

```
DELETE p
FROM map_points p
    JOIN place_relation r ON r.ancestor = p.place_id
    LEFT JOIN map_points p2 ON p2.map_id = p.map_id AND p2.place_id IN (
        SELECT child
        FROM place_relation 
        WHERE r.ancestor = ancestor 
        AND child NOT IN (20,21,31)
    )
WHERE p.place_id IN (20,21,31)
AND p2.place_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many conditions in the `left join`:

```
DELETE p
FROM map_points p JOIN
     place_relation r
     ON r.ancestor = p.place_id LEFT JOIN
     map_points p2
     ON p2.place_id = r.child
WHERE p.place_id IN ( 20, 31 ) AND p2.place_id IS NULL;
```

Basically, your conditions were too restrictive, so no records in `p2` could match.  Hence, the final condition, `p2.place_id = NULL` would generally be true -- and too many records would be deleted.